# Нужно проверить верность строки по нескольким условиям

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно проверить строку:

1. в строке должно быть от 4 до 15 символов
2. только два пробела
3. Не должно быть пробелов в начале и в конце строки.
4. Не должно быть два пробела подряд.

Использую python, какой диалект регулярок он использует, я понятия не имею, даже не знал до сих пор, что есть диалекты.

Можно ли построить одним выражением?
Спасибо.

Comment: можно. особенно если используемый диалект регулярок позволяет просмотры вперед/назад без захвата. Но вы не указали какой диалект используется, поэтому нельзя

Comment: Я не знал, что в регулярках есть диалекты.

Comment: Есть, отличаются между собой PCRE (он же perl, он же самый мощный, как мне кажется), POSIX (практически самый первый вариант из UNIX систем), javascript (что то среднее между POSIX и PCRE), java (кроме базовых вещей сам в себе), python, C#, golang. Ну и в других языках может встречаться что то из этого или что то особое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCRE:

```
^(?=^.{4,15}$)([^ ]+ ){2}[^ ]+$
```

Сначала идет забегающая вперед проверка (`(?=)`), на количество символов. А потом, опять с начала строки, потому что первое условие не изменило "текущего символа", буквально "не пробел" с одним пробелом два раза и опять не пробелы до конца строки.

Тест на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mAomVJ/2)

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Принцип я понял, дальше сам доделаю.